# 404 router.umd.js Not Found, Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular, npm

I am trying to run an Angular 2 project and implemenet `@angular/router`.

The app works fine, until I try:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
```

because it tries to find:

```
http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js
```

which results in:

```
Error: GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js 404 (Not Found)
```

**There is no /bundle/router.umd.js**

Angular tries to find this file because of:

```
var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
];

// Bundled (~40 requests):
    function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
    }
```

Here is `package.json`:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
  "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
  "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
  "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
  "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
  "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
...
```

I try and update the package using `npm install @angular/router` but get this error:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.3
└── @angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.7
```

I realize Angular2 is still in Beta. Any help here?

Comment: **temporary fix** :  if you are not using angular2-in-memory-web-api, then remove it from package.json, change angular/router version to alpha 8, delete node_modules folder , and run npm install again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure the package will change since it's still alpha but until then you could take it out of the ngPackageNames object and load it in the packages object as

```
'@angular/router': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }
```

I don't think it conforms with the other modules' pattern yet

Here is an example I tried and appears to get the correct router: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/JScearcy/087d2b2a566a92eeff538cb9854f097f)

Comment: Just to be clear I edited my question. The file doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: Correct, the router package doesn't have a bundle at the moment. It needs to be loaded separately from the other items due to that issue. That means removing it from the ngPackageNames object and adding it to the package object as above